# Imprimir PHP en vivo y no esperar que termine todo el bucle while

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas, lo que intento hacer es en un while imprimir en vivo cada recorrido, ya que en PHP espera que termine todo el bucle while o for para recién mostrarse en pantalla todo lo imprimido.

Parecido a un formulario con ajax, pero así lo haga con ajax, va imprimir al final terminando el while por php.

He intentado hacer append de jquery pero es lo mismo.

Supongo que tengo que trabajar con javascript para que imprima en vivo.

Esto lo hago porque mis scripts demoran demasiado en imprimirse y quiero monitorear si está avanzado o se ha atascado colgandose en algo.

Algunas sugerencias por favor

Comment: Y donde está tu código? PHP es código ejecutado desde el servidor, y javascript en el cliente, por lo que si necesitas que se ejecute algo asincrono necesitas utilizar la tecnología Ajax

Comment: El codigo sería cualquiera por ejemplo:

<?php
while ($this = current($array))
{
echo "Listo <br>";
}
?>

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio, primeramente te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. En cuanto a la realización de preguntas es **muy importante revisar [ask]**, esto para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas excelente respuestas, saludos.

Comment: No sé por qué estaría mal, sigo todas las indicaciones del Cómo preguntar, estoy pidiendo ideas, no estoy diciendo no sé que está mal en mi código

Comment: Goafok, la comunidad es para problemás concretos, debes proporcionar ejemplos y casos específicos, podrían haber muchos factores que modifiquen el resultado y muchas formas de realizarlo.

Comment: *Esto lo hago porque **mis scripts demoran demasiado en imprimirse** y quiero monitorear si está avanzado o se ha atascado colgandose en algo.* Lo que necesitas es **optimizar tus scripts**, los cuales no deberían tardar tanto. Ese es el problema. Cualquier solución que no pase por una optimización del código no será nunca una *solución*.

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema con la ejecución del código del lado del servidor, el servidor esperará a tener todo el flujo de datos procesado para enviar un simpĺe texto plano al navegador del cliente... por ello sugiero investigues la forma de utilizar AJAX que esto no es parte de lo que responde SO.

Comment: A. Cedano, mis scripts demoran mucho porque utilizo fopen y abro muchas páginas para verificar el estado en el que están, son como 10 000 solicitudes de fopen y tarda bastante, mis scripts no son mucho código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP, por lo general, maneja un búfer de salida, enviando al navegador paquetes con cierta cantidad de datos. La forma más sencilla de comenzar a imprimir es vaciando ese búfer:

```
while(/* condición */) {
    /* Aquí el armado de tu HTML */
    flush();
}
```

Función **[flush()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.flush.php)**.

Comment: Claro, eso era lo que estaba buscando, resuelve al 99% mi problema, gracias!